# Plotting Euclidean plane in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to plot a graph which, for each edge in the dataset, will plot a line in an n*n grid.

> For example, for a grid of 4*4
>
> ```
> ****
> ****
> ****
> ****
>
> the edge [[1,3], [2,1]] will draw a line between (1,3) and (2,3). 
>
> **0*
> 0***
> ****
> ****
> ```

Comment: Sorry I should have explained my question. How can I plot an array representation of an euclidian plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with shoes http://shoesrb.com/

Shoes.app do

a =   your array

```
  strokewidth 1.0
  spread = 10
  stroke black
  fill black
  shape do
    x = a.first
    a.each do |x|
      oval x[0]*spread-2.5, x[1]*spread-2.5, 5
    end
    fill white
    move_to x[0]*spread, x[1]*spread
    a.each do |x|
      line_to x[0]*spread, x[1]*spread
   end   
  end
end
```